# Keeping a Core Animation transition persistent?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a custom `UILabel` that I want to add a transition to when the text changes.

I create a transition:

```
CATransition *a = [CATransition animation];
a.duration = 1.0;
a.type = kCATransitionPush;
self.transition = a;
```

I set the transition to a property in my class.  Here's the method I call to update the text:

```
- (void)postMessage:(NSString *)message {    
    [self.messageLabel.layer addAnimation:self.transition forKey:@"statusAnimation"];
    self.messageLabel.text = message;
}
```

This all works fine.  However, I don't want to keep adding the animation to my label.  That slows it down every time I update.

My question is - how can I keep this transition persistent so it shows an animation every single time I call this method without having to add it manually every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking isn't quite possible.  Core Animation is a stateful library, and copies the animation object you present, then releases it upon completion.  If you are having issues with performance, you should be using the animation block methods.  [This overview of Core Animation with blocks](http://objcolumnist.com/2010/09/19/core-animation-using-blocks/) should help you get started.